# Unable to settext in jlabels in function sendReceivedata

Tags: java, swing, java.util.scanner, jlabel

The main problem I am getting is unable to set labels in static function sendReceivedata ...netbeans generated code for all jcomponents is private I can't modify them and if I call sendReceivedata function within constructor 
then the program will execute but not show gui

Main problem : unable to set labels in static function

```
public class Server extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    static public Socket socket;

    public static void sendReceivedata()
    {
        try
        {
            ServerSocket serverSocket=new ServerSocket(8181);
            jLabel2.setText("Server is waiting for Connection");
            while(true)
            {
                //waiting for connection
                socket = serverSocket.accept();
                jLabel3.setText("Connected");
                //ready for reading message from client
                System.out.println("Connected");
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

                String receivemsg=br.readLine();
                String receivemsg1=br.readLine();

                jLabel4.setText("Data Receive From Client is ");
                jLabel5.setText(receivemsg);
                jLabel6.setText(receivemsg1);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("ab "+e);
        }
    }

    public Server()
    {
        super("Server Side");
        initComponents();
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        //</editor-fold>
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                new Server().setVisible(true);      
            }
        });
        sendReceivedata();
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTable jTable1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The *problem* is that the `sendReceivedata()` is not executing with the *Event Dispatcher Thread* (EDT) context, which is the thread which is responsible of updating graphic elements, thus, any UI operations you do will not be made visible.

To solve this problem, you would need to use the [`SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Runnable run)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater-java.lang.Runnable-). Since, in your case you are updating multiple labels, I'd recommend that you have a method for each label, something like so:

```
private static updateJLabel2(final String text) {
    final JLabel l = jLabel2;
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            l.setText(text);
        }
    }
}
```

And call it like so:

```
try {
ServerSocket serverSocket=new ServerSocket(8181);
updateJLabel2("Server is waiting for Connection");
...
```

As a side note, please give your labels more relevant names.

As another side note, please do not place `sendReceivedata();` just after `new Server().setVisible(true);`. Although doing so *should* have the same affect as my answer, you would also be doing non UI operations on the UI thread which would cause your interface to freeze.